# ¿Cuales son los formularios abiertos en la aplicación actualmente?

Tags: formularios, delphi

Tengo una aplicación ya hecha en Delphi6.

Necesito saber en un momento determinado de la ejecución de la aplicación, si un formulario en concreto (FormCambioCuentas) está abierto. La consulta se hace desde un Timer que se puede poner en marcha después de que el form esté abierto.

Puedo usar una variable global, pero me gustaría saber si hay otra forma.

Gracias.

Comment: Hola Manuel podrias marcar como aceptada la respuesta que te halla resultado mas util, gracias

Answer (score 3):

```
for i := 0 to Screen.FormCount - 1 do
begin
    if Screen.Forms[i].Showing then
    begin
       if (Screen.Forms[i].Caption = 'MiFormulario') then
       begin
          //El formulario está abierto
       end;
    end;
end;
```

Debes utilizar la **variable Screen**(ya definida por **Delphi**). Haciendo uso de esta variable haces un **ciclo for** que recorrerá todos tus formularios y preguntará si están mostrándose, de ser cierto entonces se preguntará si la **propiedad Caption**(o cualquiera que sirva para identificar tus formularios de manera única) es igual al formulario que buscas, de ser cierto, pues harás lo que deseas.

Comment: Utilizando este código de Japv, yo haría un pequeño cambio. en lugar de comporar en el IF utilizando el Caption, utilizaría la clase del formulario. El Caption puede cambiar, la clase no.

Comment: Gracias, el código funciona bien.

Comment: @Manuel.Estivaliz no olvides marcar como aceptada a alguna de las respuestas dadas

Answer (score 1):

Me baso en el código anterior de [Japv](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/189826/japv) y añado la modificación que he añadido en el comentario.
Creo que es mejor hacer la comparación por la clase del formulario que no por el `Caption` que podría cambiar.

El mismno código con esa pequeña modificación:

```
for i := 0 to Screen.FormCount - 1 do
begin
    if Screen.Forms[i].Showing then
    begin
       // AnsiCompareText para evitar mayúsculas y minúsculas
       if (Ansicomparetext(Screen.Forms[i].ClassName, 'TMiFormulario')=0) then
       begin
          //El formulario esta abierto
       end;
    end;
end;
```

O mejor utilizando el operador `IS`.
En ambos casos serviría para todos los formularios de la misma clase.

```
for i := 0 to Screen.FormCount - 1 do
begin
    if Screen.Forms[i].Showing then
    begin
       if (Screen.Forms[i] is TMiFormulario) then
       begin
          //El formulario esta abierto
       end;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Gracias, lo probaré también.  La segunda me parece mejor para no depender de las cadenas.